# OpenGL sources: Libglu1-mesa-dev depends on libglu1-mesa (= 8.0.2-0ubuntu3) but 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.7 is to be installed

Tags: 12.04, package-management, opengl, r, mesa

When trying to install an R package (`rgl`, which makes 3-D plots), R gives the following error:

> configure: error: missing required header GL/glu.h ERROR:
>   configuration failed for package ‘rgl’

So I learnt that glu.h is a source file from OpenGL and that I should install the sources of "Mesa OpenGL Utility Library" that are in he package `libglu1-mesa-dev`.

So, I try to install this package, but it complains about dependencies:

```
$sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev

libglu1-mesa-dev: Depends: libglu1-mesa (= 8.0.2-0ubuntu3) but
8.0.4-0ubuntu0.7 is to be installed
```

**System**:

Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

```
$lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core
Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06) 

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars XTX [Radeon HD 8790M]


$sudo apt-get -f install

Reading package lists... Done 
Done Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove
and 1 not upgraded.
```

Hoz can I fix or bypass this dependency problem to install `libglu1-mesa-dev`?